# Integrating Whatsapp API in symfony

Tags: php, symfony, whatsapp

I am trying to integrate the WHAnonymous API in my symfony project.

I have included it in my project using composer install and it is now in my vendor folder.

But I am not understanding how to import it into my project!

This is my manager class.

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Managers;

use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;


class WhatsAppManager
{

  private $test;
  /**
   * Constructor
   */
  public function __construct()
  {
      $this->test =1;
  }

  public function sendMessage()
  {
    $username = ""; // Your number with country code, ie: 34123456789
    $nickname = ""; // Your nickname, it will appear in push notifications
    $debug = true;  // Shows debug log

    // Create a instance of WhastPort.
    $w = new WhatsProt($username, $nickname, $debug);
    var_dump("In send message method");
  }
}
 ?>
```

I have used

```
require_once 'whatsprot.class.php';
```

and

```
require_once 'Whatsapp\Bundle\Chat-api\src\whatsprot.class.php';
```

and

```
use Whatsapp\Bundle\Chat-api\Whatsprot
```

But it is just not working.
Please tell me the right way to do it!
And is there something i should do when i am using 3rd party vendors in symfony.

I did look into the documentation of the WHanonymous but i found only snippets of code to use it and not the way to import it.
Git repo for WHAnonymous : https://github.com/WHAnonymous

Comment: how you added app.kernel.php ??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The class doesn't have a namespace, but is correctly loaded by the autoload system created my composer. So you can reference to the class without any include or require directive but simply with a `\` as example:

```
   // Create a instance of WhastPort.
    $w = new \WhatsProt($username, $nickname, $debug);
```

Hope this help

Comment: But can you explain me how it worked?
The path in composer is whatsapp/chat-api.

But the path for this class is whatsapp/chat-api/src/whatsprot.class.php.

Comment: hi @user3425344 the library don't respect the [standard PRS-0](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-0/) but the composer is able to load correctly the classes